# How can I control a remote machine if I know its admin account and password?

Tags: windows, services, port, remote-access

A while back I came across some software with which I could fully control a remote machine, but I can't remember its name. I now want to do some automation from my server so that I can put files on remote client machines, execute some commands, or get a list of processes on client machines.

I don't want to have any special software installed on my remote machine - I think there is a port by which I can do it. The only think I know about the client machines is the administrator account name and password.

Are there any built-in services in Windows that can be used to do this, and if so, which port does it use?

I'm aware of telnet but I don't think that's the software I had previously used.

Answer (score 1):

Depending upon what version of Windows are on your servers, Remote Desktop may be enabled.

If you are looking to move files around between servers, there are some options. Inside my LAN, I use perl to move data around between various servers (Linux, Windows, OS X). Perl lets me use defined SMB shares, or existing admin (c$) shares on Windows servers. However this is entirely within a LAN environment, and it probably not the most Windows-y type solution.

Comment: I want to automate things like sending  a remote file to targetthrought some open ports on client,executing some scripts on clients.so remote desktop cant be used

Comment: Ah, well that is a different case. I will update my answer.

Comment: I would recommend that you edit your question to add this additional information in, and perhaps offer up a bit of a description of the network connecting the various machines. I think you will get better answers that way.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to copy files by running:

copy file \\remotecomputer\c$\path

Execute remote commands and list remote processes:

psexec and pslist

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896649